# jsgrid updateItem with asmx

Tags: json, jsgrid

I wanna use the jsGrid library into project, can you help me?

How can I send the updated items to the asmx code `update.asmx`

```
 updateItem: function(item) {
     return $.ajax({
         url: "update.asmx",
         data: JSON.stringify(item),
         type: "PUT",
     });
 },
```

UPDATE.ASMX

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
  Public Function UPDATE() As List(Of String)             
End Function
```

Comment: What you are doing is on the right track. Your web method has to return the updated item, should be same as the `item` passed to the `updateItem` function, with a Http Status Code of 200.  If there are update errors, your web method should return a Http status code of anything other than 200, and the edit mode in jsGrid will not close.